# what can I do when the server refused to connect by ssh

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, maintenance

I have a server running well before but today I can not ssh to it, it shows me:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.117 port 22: Connection refused
```

I guess something is wrong with it but I can not log onto it so what can I do at this situation, at least to figure out what's the problem with it?

Comment: Did you make any changes and if so what were they ?

Comment: try verbose to see whats happening:     sudo ssh -vvv -i key.pem user@machine

Answer (score 3):

The `Connection refused` usually means that there isn't anything listening on the remote port. Did you configure sshd to listen on a different port than the standard one ? If you did then you can use

```
ssh -p <portnum> 10.0.0.117
```

Failing that you will have to access the system by it's console to see if sshd is running and on what port as well as checking logs for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have HP iLO, Dell DRAC or SUN ILOM, you can use that to login to server.

Comment: +1 Always ensure console-level access to a server, that's also why virtual servers are so nice.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Is your ssh running? (as recommended by Ian)

service status sshd

service sshd start   (if it is not running)

2 - Check if the port is open (related to (1))

netstat -talpn | grep ":22"

3 - Try temporarily disabling firewall on the ssh client and server, in case outgoing port 22 or incoming port 22 is blocked in either of the machines, respectively.

/sbin/iptables -F

4 - Can you ping the ssh server

ping 10.0.0.117

Comment: I did nothing to that server before and I can ping the server.